# ADT plugin error during installation

Tags: android, adt

I have installed eclipse classic IDE in my system(Windows 7, 64bit) and tried to install sdk tool for android app development and also i am having jdk 7 SE. Any suggestion on the below error.

"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 "

Answer (score 1):

connect with internet while installing plugin. Eclipse automatically download the dependency files.

Or see this

[ADT Installation Error: "requires plug-in org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui".](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/troubleshooting.html#installeclipsecomponents)

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse first.

Then

> Windows > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software

add repositories for your eclipse version. Then select it and press reload to lead all available toolkits. Finally restart eclipse and try installing ADT again.

By the way, I have added http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios and got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above solutions,I would like to give you one more advice that yet Eclipse does not support jre7 for android programming.So better would be you switch to jre6 or jre5(too old).